# how to download postgres data in csv format through bash script?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, csv, postgresql, database

I am able to connect to db also getting output but it's not coming in proper format. So how to get the output in csv like format and also want to save that in csv format.

```
psql -d <db> -U <user> -W -h <host> --output=datanew.csv -c "SELECT * FROM employee limit 10;"
```

Comment: As stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190632/how-to-export-a-postgresql-query-output-to-a-csv-file you need to add (FORMAT csv) in the SELECT Command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 12, `psql` has a --csv command line option.
From [the psql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> --csv
>
> ```
> Switches to CSV (Comma-Separated Values) output mode. 
> This is equivalent to \pset format csv.
> ```

If using an older version, the `COPY` SQL command may be used around the `SELECT` to export in CSV format. For example:

```
psql [other options] --output=datanew.csv -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM employee limit 10) TO STDOUT (FORMAT csv, HEADER on)"
```